# python longest repeated substring in a single string?

Tags: python, string, lcs

i can only find hints on how to make an algorithm for a longest repeated substring in two separate strings in comparing the two.  but what i need help on is how to find a longest repeated substring in one SINGLE looooong string (which is read from a text file).  i cant find any hints on how to do it.  can anyone help me please?

Comment: The first [reference I find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem) has nothing to say about two separate strings.

Comment: The second reference is [Finding the longest repeated substring](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10355103)