# How to find a longest consecutive repeated substring in a string?

Tags: java, string, longest-substring

In order to de-crypt a message, I need to first find the key. From the given information, I find the key is part of the string:

> str = "251220825122082"

We can easily get that the key should be "`2512208`" since the key is supposed to be repeatedly used in encrypting a message. However, I tried many methods and got the answer "`25122082`", which adds another 2 in the end, but it's just another beginning of the key.

The method I have tried:

1. regex: `String repeated = str.replaceAll("(.+?)\\1+", "$1");`
2. [LRS Java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/42sort/LRS.java.html)

These two provide the same answer("`25122082`").

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355103/finding-the-longest-repeated-substring

Comment: `replaceAll` is doing exactly what it's supposed to do: it replaces 25122082512208 with 2512208.  There's still a "2" left at the end of the string, which it doesn't replace.  Here, since you are trying to extract information out of a string, `replaceAll` is the wrong tool for the job.  Use `find` to search for a regex, and `group` to extract the capture group.  `replaceAll` is for replacing portions of an input string with other strings and leaving the rest of the input string alone.  That's not what you're trying to do here.

Comment: How do you know for sure that 2512208 is the key and not 25122082?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not duplicate, using that method I cannot get right answer. Even using this online demo, I cannot get right answer either. https://daniel-hug.github.io/longest-repeated-substring/

Comment: @NickZiebert because the key is repeated. If 25122082 is the key, than what's the repeated pattern? If the key is not long enough to encrypt the message, it should loop back from the beginning.

Comment: Oh, gotcha.  I assumed you were looking at lines and lines of numbers and finding the pattern with most occurrences.

Comment: Looks like something that requires a dynamic programming algorithm.

Comment: @ajb Awesome! Solved this question using find() and group(). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ajb, solved this question by using find() and group().

```
    String str = "251220825122082";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+?)\\1+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        String repeated = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(repeated);
    }
```

Output: 2512208

Comment: What I meant was that you can say `m.group(1)` to get the contents of the first group (which means the same as `\\1` in the regex or `$1` in the replacement string).  `m.group()` gives you the entire matched string, but `m.group(1)` gives you exactly the key you need.  You don't need another `replaceAll` after that.

Comment: Thank you! But what if the key is "5122082", how do I find it?

Comment: If the input string is `str` above, and the "longest consecutive repeated substring" is the key, then it's ambiguous.  Both 2512208 and 5122082 meet the criteria, and both are equally long.  If you have a rule that would make it clear that 5122082 is the key (such as, the _last_ substring in the file is chosen in case of a tie), then there may be a way to adjust the code to follow the rule.  If you don't have a rule, then there is no solution--there's no way to decide between the two.

Comment: This approach could only get "first repeated string". For `str = "22512208225122082"`, this approach gets "2" 4 times, instead of the right answer "25122082"