# Longest common sub string in a set of strings JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, longest-substring

I was trying to find longest common substring in a set of strings in JavaScript.

I got the idea from [Find the longest common starting substring in a set of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916218/find-the-longest-common-starting-substring-in-a-set-of-strings)

**but I am not only looking for staring sub string**

So, I went ahead with following:

I guess it works as expected but there is an overhead of `map` and `sort`.

```
function longestCommonSubstring(array) {
    // Copy the array
    let arr = array.slice().sort();
    // For each individual string sort them 
    arr = arr.map(a => a.split('').sort().join(''));
    // Check the first and last string and check till chars match
    let a0 = arr[0],
        aLast = arr[arr.length -1],
        len = arr[0].length,
        i = 0;
    while(i < len && a0[i] === aLast[i]) i++;
    // return
    return a0.substring(0,i);
}
```

Am I doing any wrong? Can it be done in much more efficient way ?

**INPUT ["abc","cxabgi"]**

**OUTPUT ["ab"]**

Comment: I'm confused about `arr = arr.map(a => a.split('').sort().join(''));`, if you sort each input string lexiographically, you've lost the original order, which will make it impossible to determine what a matching substring would be. Your current code results in 'abc', not 'ab'.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ok yes. My bad :( So how to approach the problem then ?

Comment: I’m struggling to see how your question differs from the linked one, or any of those in its related list, like https://stackoverflow.com/q/10355103/215552

Answer (score 0):

```js
function longestCommonSubstring(array) {
  const sortedArray = [...array].sort();
  const firstItem = sortedArray[0];
  const lastItem = sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 1];
  const firstItemLength = firstItem.length;
  let i = 0;

  while (i < firstItemLength && firstItem.charAt(i) === lastItem.charAt(i)) {
    i++;
  }

  return firstItem.substring(0, i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function commonSubstring(substr, str) {
let awr = '';
let match;
if (str.includes(substr)) return substr;
for (let i = 0; i < substr.length; i++) {
    match = '';
    if (str.includes(substr[i])) {
        match += substr[i];
        if (match.length > awr.length)
            awr = match;
        for (j = 1; i + j < substr.length; j++) {
            if (str.includes(match + substr[i + j])) {
                match += substr[i + j];
                if (match.length > awr.length)
                    awr = match;
                continue;
            }
            else break;
        }
    }
}
return awr;
```

}